# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError [INVALID_TYPE]: Supplied options is not an object

Tags: javascript, promise, discord.js

I'm making a discord bot with Discord.JS, but when I try to do a command it shows me this error:

```
(node:4) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError [INVALID_TYPE]: Supplied options is not an object. at Message.delete (/app/node_modules/discord.js/src/structures/Message.js:501:44) at /app/commands/warn.js:3:89.
```

The warn.js code is:

```
module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {
    let target = message.mentions.members.first()
    if(!target) return message.channel.send("Couldn't find that ID!").then(m => m.delete(15000))

    let reason = args.slice(1).join(" ")
    if(!reason) return message.channel.send(`Please give a reason to warn **${target.user.tag}**!`).then(m => m.delete(15000))

    message.channel.send(`Warned **${target.user.tag}**!`).then(m => m.delete(15000))
    // get role by name
let myRole = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "Warned");
target.addRole(role).catch(console.error);

}

module.exports.help = {
    name: "warn",
    aliases: []
}
```

I don't really know why it's happening, and I can't find the error.
Can someone look at the code and see what's wrong? I'd be really grateful.

Answer (score 0):

The delete function expects an object for it's parameter, and you can specify the timeout in that.

```
    if(!reason) return message.channel.send(`Please give a reason to warn **${target.user.tag}**!`).then(m => m.delete({timeout: 15000}))
```

Answer (score 0):

In javascript there is multiple way to handle asynchronous code.

In your example you are using an `async` function. This means you could use the [async/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Instructions/async_function) - this feature is built on top of `Promise` with syntax sugar.
It allows you to write your code in a "synchronous" way.
So you may want to rewrite your Promise call like this:

```js
module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {
    let target = message.mentions.members.first()
    if(!target) {
      const message = await message.channel.send("Couldn't find that ID!"); 
      return message.delete(15000)
    }
```

Also the error `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning` alerts you that you have an error in your Promise execution. Here the parameter given to the `delete` function is of the wrong type. An object is expected, but a number is received. Here is the [documentation of the message API](http://documentation%20of%20the%20message%20API).

To go a step further, you can handle the Promises rejection with the `.catch` chaining function, it can be useful to debug or log the error.

```js
// Promises style
let target = message.mentions.members.first()

if(!target) {
  return message.channel.send("Couldn't find that ID!")
  .then(m => m.delete(15000))
  .catch(error => console.log(error))
}
```

Or using async/await syntax:

```js
// async/await style
let target = message.mentions.members.first()

if(!target) {
  try {
    const message = await message.channel.send("Couldn't find that ID!"); 
    return message.delete(15000)
  } catch(error) {
    console.log(error)
  }
}
```

Comment: I changed it to that, and now it shows a new error: TypeError: target.addRole is not a function.

Comment: It comes from the code `target.addRole(role).catch(console.error);`
I dont know discordJS in details, but it looks like your target object does not have `addRole` method. You may want to read the docs or just log the target object

Comment: Maybe you are looking for this method: https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/master/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=edit
`target.edit({ roles: [...] })`